# Batch file to identify default ip and gateway , in multi nic OS

Tags: file, batch-file

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims={,}" %%a in ('"WMIC NICConfig where IPEnabled="True" get DefaultIPGateway /value | find "I" "') do echo IPv4 %%~a
```

kindly help me to get the IP address associated with this default gateway too, it should match the NIC id. if multiple gateway found then script should show multiple gateway and exit, if single gateway found it should display the IP address and gateway.

Let me explain the scenario -

(scenario one)

----Server 1 with two nic card---

-------NIC1------------

ip-      10.10.0.2

Subnet - 255.255.255.0

Gw -     10.10.0.1

--------NIC2----------

Ip-      172.16.0.2

Subnet - 255.255.0.0

GW- No gateway defined

In this scenario desired Script output should be ---

Default IP Address 10.10.0.2
Default Gateway    10.10.0.1
.

(scenario two)

----Server 1 with two nic card---

-------NIC1------------
ip-      10.10.0.2

Subnet - 255.255.255.0

Gw -     10.10.0.1

--------NIC2----------

Ip-      172.16.0.2

Subnet - 255.255.0.0

GW-      172.16.0.1

In this scenario desired Script output should be ---

Multiple gateway found

10.10.0.1
172.16.0.1

and it exit                 .

Comment: Just an idea, have you considered trying this with powershell? It typically makes things like this a lot easier when you don't have to parse string output of different commands...

Comment: actually powershell is blocked due to high security concern in servers

Comment: If it is a multi NIC machine, how are we, or the script supposed to determine which is the target NIC? More than one can be enabled and connected at the same time, and whilst I understand you want to show all of the gateways in such a scenario, you will only ever see one IP address if only one is enabled and connected at the time the script is being run. However, that would not necessarily be your intended target. Please explain better your task.

Comment: in windows only one gateway is permitted, the nic having the gateway is the main target nic, if multiple gateway found then the script should show multiple gateway found , that will be considered as error, as it is not a proper scenario. if only one gateway found then it should display that gateway and the ip associated/mentioned in that nic card. this is the main requirement. to get the default ip and gateway and eliminate error in case multiple gateway defined in system

Comment: In theory, each interface could have its own default gateway. Are you telling us that Windows does not allow the interfaces to do that? If that was the case, (you can only have one default gateway), then why would you have logic in your script for an impossible scenario?

Comment: if you add multiple gateway windows will throw warning, that it will not work properly, you can set it though, just trying to avoid this manual error

Comment: I should also mention that the value type of DefaultIPGateway is an array, this menas that it could return multiple addresses, for example `{xxx.xxx.x.xxx xxx.xxx.x.xx xxx.xxx.x.x}`. So is your criteria not to report any NIC with all addresses not matching in the same order? all addresses not matching in any order? or where all arrays do not hold at least one matching address?

Comment: Your [Edit] does not answer the scenario I mentioned above. Please remember that you have already told us that there could be manual errors, so cannot guarantee that the DefaultIPGateway array cannot consist of more than one address.

Comment: manual error means, if user add a gateway in nic 2 instead of windows os warning. 
usually we do not add a second gateway in any nic card, we add it in route add command

Comment: Usually you do not add a different gateway on a second NIC, so what is the difference between that and adding two or more in any order? Both are possibilities. So, if it is not possible at all in your environments, you need to specify that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "spaces=                                               "

FOR /f "skip=1delims=" %%e IN ('WMIC NICConfig') do SET "line=%%e"&CALL :analyse

GOTO :EOF

:analyse

IF "%line:~20,1%"=="" GOTO :eof

FOR %%y IN (defipgatew ipaddress whatever macaddress) DO SET "%%y="

SET "defipgatew=%line:~146,18%"
SET "defipgatew=%defipgatew: =%"
IF NOT DEFINED defipgatew GOTO ipaddress
SET "defipgatew=%defipgatew:~2,-2%

:ipaddress
SET "ipaddress=%line:~552,48%"
SET "ipaddress=%ipaddress: =%"
IF NOT DEFINED ipaddress GOTO macaddress
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=," %%b IN ("%ipaddress:~1,-1%") do set "ipaddress=%%~b"&set "whatever=%%~c"

:macaddress
SET "macaddress=%line:~915,17%"
SET "macaddress=%macaddress: =%"
IF NOT DEFINED macaddress GOTO next1

:next1

:: Gate any unwanted lines here. For instance if you want to suppress a line where varname is not set, use
:: if not defined varname goto :eof

IF "%defipgatew%%ipaddress%%whatever%%macaddress%" == "" GOTO :eof
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%y IN (defipgatew ipaddress whatever macaddress) DO SET "%%y=!%%y!%spaces%"
:: varnames now padded with oodles of trailing spaces.
:: change %varname% to %varname:~0,len% to produce the varname in a field of len characters
ECHO %defipgatew% %ipaddress% %whatever% %macaddress%
ENDLOCAL
GOTO :eof
```

On my machine, this routine extracts the data that seems to be of interest.

Read a `WMIC NICConfig` output, assigning each line to `line` via `%%e`.

Then analyse the line, grabbing the various fields using their offset within `line`

The very last line will assign a value to `line` that is difficult to see. I believe it's a single `CR`, so if the (I chose 21<sup>st</sup>) character doesn't exist, don't process that line.

Otherwise, grab the appropriate field, strip it of spaces, if it's not empty, remove the decoration.

If none of the fields has been set, exit. Otherwise, pad each field with trailing spaces and report.

Up to you which fieldlength you want to choose, presence/sequence of fields.

Comment: thanks Magoo, I was expecting your reply, I will try it and let you know

Comment: It is giving too many errors (too long to post here)- can you please make the batch simple like 
it will find the default gateway and Ip mentioned in the same nic, InterfaceIndex should be same for gateway and ip, if same, it will display the ip and gateway. 
if ip starts with 10.10 it will redirect to :subnetA if ip start with 172.16 it will redirect to :subnetB